# How to get the domain name from an ipaddress

Tags: networking

I want to resolve a IP address to a domain name but I don't get the desired result.

I want to retrieve the real web name something like this "google.com" from the ip address "74.125.225.100" but what I get is "ord08s08-in-f4.1e100.net"

I tried using whois and the traceroute commands in linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no unique relation beetween an ip and a domain name.
What you get with traceroute is a computer name.
But one computer may host dozens of domains.

Comment: Agree. But what I'm trying is there a way to find out the domain name from a given IP address ?

Comment: Yes, and thats the problem. domain -> ip : unique, ip -> domain : not unique

Comment: Since multiple domains can be hosted on a sever, so there can be multiple domains associated with an ip address.[this](http://reverseip.logontube.com/?url=74.125.225.103&output=json) will list all the domains running that ip address.

Answer (score 1):

you can use nslookup command in linux.

using `nslookup <ip address>` you can resolve the domain name of the IP address.

this is the  [link](http://help.lockergnome.com/linux/resolve-IP-address-hostname--ftopict413770.html)  to a similar post.

Comment: nslookup will be able to resolve only if the entry is present in the hosts file or in the dns records. how about finding the domain name of google.com or facebook.com ? from an ipaddress.

Answer (score 0):

http://whois.net/domain-name-ip-address/ This is exactly what you are searching for.

Comment: this is same a running the whois command on terminal, only that the output is displayed on a webpage.